# MySQL count number of user activities (table a) falling in two login session datetime (table b)

Tags: mysql, count, between

I have a table with all the users activities and another table with all the users login events. Each of them has a datatime field (`creation`).

I need to count for a specific user with one query how many activities he/she has done falling into the datetime range in between two consecutive logins (assuming that in between a logout or session expiration event has happened) and after the last one.

```
CREATE TABLE `STAGING_admin_activities` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `admin_id` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `requested_URL_and_data` tinytext DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_data` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `result` tinytext DEFAULT NULL,
  `useragent_referred_URL` tinytext DEFAULT NULL,
  `useragent_browser` tinytext DEFAULT NULL,
  `useragent_browser_version` tinytext DEFAULT NULL,
  `useragent_robot` tinytext DEFAULT NULL,
  `useragent_mobile` tinytext DEFAULT NULL,
  `useragent_platform` tinytext DEFAULT NULL,
  `useragent_languages` tinytext DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_country_code` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remarks` tinytext DEFAULT NULL,
  `creation` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `STAGING_admin_login_logout` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `operation` enum('login','logout') NOT NULL,
  `result` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin_id` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_country_code` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creation` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

To simplify the data example keeping just the meaningful fields

**STAGING_admin_login_logout**

| id | admin_id | operation | creation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | login | 08/03/2021 17:19 |
| 2 | 5 | login | 08/03/2021 20:11 |
| 3 | 1 | login | 09/03/2021 09:09 |
| 4 | 4 | login | 09/03/2021 10:31 |
| 5 | 5 | login | 09/03/2021 15:08 |
| 6 | 5 | login | 09/03/2021 17:01 |
| 7 | 1 | login | 10/03/2021 14:01 |
| 8 | 5 | login | 10/03/2021 18:15 |

**STAGING_admin_activities**

| id | admin_id | creation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 08/03/2021 17:20 |
| 2 | 5 | 08/03/2021 17:23 |
| 3 | 5 | 08/03/2021 17:25 |
| 4 | 5 | 08/03/2021 20:13 |
| 5 | 5 | 08/03/2021 20:13 |
| 6 | 4 | 09/03/2021 10:33 |
| 7 | 5 | 09/03/2021 15:11 |
| 8 | 5 | 09/03/2021 15:11 |
| 9 | 5 | 09/03/2021 15:22 |
| 10 | 5 | 09/03/2021 17:01 |
| 11 | 1 | 10/03/2021 14:01 |
| 12 | 5 | 10/03/2021 18:18 |
| 13 | 5 | 10/03/2021 19:37 |

the expected result is something similar of this simplified table

expected results filtered on admin_id = 5

| admin_id | login_time | last_activity_time | **number_of_activities** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 08/03/2021 17:19 | 08/03/2021 17:25 | **3** |
| 5 | 08/03/2021 20:11 | 08/03/2021 20:13 | **2** |
| 5 | 09/03/2021 15:08 | 09/03/2021 15:22 | **3** |
| 5 | 09/03/2021 17:01 | 09/03/2021 17:01 | **1** |
| 5 | 10/03/2021 18:15 | 10/03/2021 19:37 | **2** |

As you can see the field last_activity_time come from the activties table "creation" field and is the higher datetime in between two login events. The last column number_of_activities is the desired result, the number of activities including the last one falling in the time range between login_time (originally coming from the 'creation' field of the login events table) and last_activity_time (originally coming from the 'creation' field of the activities table).

In the following image, it is shown the relations on the datetime field of the two tables and how they are considered on creating the resulting one.

[image: logic behind the final table creation]

Concerning the DB version on PhpMyAdmin I can read this: "Versione del server: 10.3.32-MariaDB - MariaDB Server".

**UPDATE 1**

Following D-Shih ideas I tryed this

```
SELECT *
FROM
( SELECT operation,result,admin_id,creation as login_creation, LEAD(creation) OVER(PARTITION BY admin_id ORDER BY creation) next_login_time 
FROM STAGING_admin_login_logout
WHERE operation = "login" AND admin_id = 5 ) login_logout
INNER JOIN STAGING_admin_activities ON STAGING_admin_activities.admin_id = login_logout.admin_id
WHERE STAGING_admin_activities.creation BETWEEN login_logout.login_creation AND login_logout.next_login_time
ORDER BY STAGING_admin_activities.creation ASC
```

that actually gives as many rows as the ativities of user with user_id = 5 and falling in the range of datetime of two consecutive logins. What is in common to all the activities rows in between two logins is the field login_creation that has the same datetime. Now I should count the activities that as the same login_creation field value; I tryed in this way

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) as number_of_activities
FROM
( SELECT operation,result,admin_id,creation as login_creation, LEAD(creation) OVER(PARTITION BY admin_id ORDER BY creation) next_login_time 
FROM STAGING_admin_login_logout
WHERE operation = "login" AND admin_id = 5 ) login_logout
INNER JOIN STAGING_admin_activities ON STAGING_admin_activities.admin_id = login_logout.admin_id
WHERE STAGING_admin_activities.creation BETWEEN login_logout.login_creation AND login_logout.next_login_time
GROUP BY login_logout.login_creation
ORDER BY STAGING_admin_activities.creation ASC
```

now checking if it is correct.

**UPDATE 2**

The query closest to the desired result is the following one, I still have a couple of troubles for which I kind ask for an help

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) as number_of_activities, MAX(STAGING_admin_activities.creation) as last_activity_creation, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,login_creation,next_login_time) as time_lenght
FROM
    ( SELECT operation,result,admin_id,creation as login_creation, LEAD(creation) OVER(PARTITION BY admin_id ORDER BY creation) next_login_time 
    FROM STAGING_admin_login_logout
    WHERE operation = "login" AND admin_id = 5 ) login_logout
INNER JOIN STAGING_admin_activities ON STAGING_admin_activities.admin_id = login_logout.admin_id
WHERE STAGING_admin_activities.creation BETWEEN login_logout.login_creation AND login_logout.next_login_time AND
      requested_URL_and_data = '/adminPanel/Products/addUpdate' AND
      login_logout.result = 1      
GROUP BY login_logout.login_creation
ORDER BY STAGING_admin_activities.creation ASC
```

The first problem is that the last group of activities have a time range equal in between the last login creation datatime and NULL since there is not a next login time that determines the end of the range. I need to extract some how the last/max activity creation datetime, lets call it 'max_activity_creation', and extend the condition on time as following

```
WHERE (STAGING_admin_activities.creation BETWEEN login_logout.login_creation AND login_logout.next_login_time **OR STAGING_admin_activities.creation >= max_activity_creation**) AND
      requested_URL_and_data = '/adminPanel/Products/addUpdate' AND
      login_logout.result = 1
```

How can I extract this 'max_activity_creation' value?

The second issue is that I should calculate the time length of the activities as the datetime of the last activity before a new login and the datetime of the previous login. Let's call the dateime of this last activity as 'last_activity_creation' as in the initial `SELECT`.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) as number_of_activities, MAX(STAGING_admin_activities.creation) as last_activity_creation, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,login_creation,next_login_time) as time_lenght
```

actually 'last_activity_creation' is displayed correctly but if I use it in side the TIMESTAMPDIFF

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,login_creation,last_activity_creation)
```

I get an error. Any ideas?

Comment: Posting some example data and expected results based on that example data would help us out . Also posting your MySQL version would help us out as MySQL 8 makes consecutive query types more easy

Comment: thank you i tried to add simplified data table to better explain what I am trying to get. And I copied the version number of the MariaDB server. Hope this could be useful.

Comment: @fede72bari What's the logic of `id admin_id` from your expect result

Comment: id is as usually the primary key of the table with autoincrement; so no logic on it. admin_id is the id of the administrator, in the given example it is filtered on admin_id=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @D-Shih here is the solution

```
SELECT a.admin_id,
       a.creation login_time,
       MAX(activity.creation) last_activity_time,
       count(*) number_of_activities
       
FROM ( 
  SELECT *, LEAD(creation) OVER(PARTITION BY admin_id ORDER BY creation) next_logout_time 
  FROM STAGING_admin_login_logout
) a
INNER JOIN STAGING_admin_activities activity
ON a.admin_id = activity.admin_id AND 
activity.creation BETWEEN  a.creation AND coalesce(next_logout_time,'9999/12/31') AND
coalesce(next_logout_time,'9999/12/31')  <> activity.creation
WHERE  a.admin_id = 5
GROUP BY a.admin_id,
       a.creation;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `LEAD` window function in asubquery on `STAGING_admin_activities` table to get the next `creation` in every row.

then use `BETWEEN` to filter your expectation logic.

**Query #1**

```
SELECT a.admin_id,
       a.creation login_time,
       MAX(logout.creation) last_activity_time,
       count(*) number_of_activities
       
FROM ( 
  SELECT *, LEAD(creation) OVER(PARTITION BY admin_id ORDER BY creation) next_logout_time 
  FROM STAGING_admin_activities
) a
INNER JOIN STAGING_admin_login_logout logout
ON a.admin_id = logout.admin_id AND 
logout.creation BETWEEN  a.creation AND coalesce(next_logout_time,'9999/12/31') AND
coalesce(next_logout_time,'9999/12/31') <> logout.creation
WHERE  a.admin_id = 5
GROUP BY a.admin_id,
       a.creation;
```

| admin_id | login_time | last_activity_time | number_of_activities |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2021-03-08 17:19:00 | 2021-03-08 17:25:00 | 3 |
| 5 | 2021-03-08 20:11:00 | 2021-03-08 20:13:00 | 2 |
| 5 | 2021-03-09 15:08:00 | 2021-03-09 15:22:00 | 3 |
| 5 | 2021-03-09 17:01:00 | 2021-03-09 17:01:00 | 1 |
| 5 | 2021-03-10 18:15:00 | 2021-03-10 19:37:00 | 2 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=05d06861e67beceb189670298f849533)

`LEAD` window function will return the value from the nth row after the current row in a partition.

Comment: thank you I am trying to understand completely the logic since I didn't know the function LEAD.  I will back as soon as I will have a clearer picture of your smart solution, for now I just tryed on the fly and got a sintax error "#1064 - Errore di sintassi nella query SQL vicino a ''9999/12/31') OVER(PARTITION BY admin_id ORDER BY creation) next_logout_time ...' linea 7". I have to better understand the condition "logout.creation BETWEEN  a.creation AND next_logout_time AND" wondering if it correct since we have to count activities in between two login events,not logins between events

Comment: @fede72bari I edit my answer, due to `LEAD` window function didn't support multiple parameter way

Comment: dear @D-Shih i applied your query modified that right is running without errors, but it counts always 1 activity as if it is considering just the first or the last activity between two login events. I added an explicative image in the question text.

Comment: @fede72bari What do you mean? Do this query work as your expectation from your question?

Comment: thank you for your suggestions and attempts, but regretfully the query gives as result always 1 activity counted in between two logins despite the real number of activities that is generally more than 1.

Comment: @fede72bari  Is this query be able to your expect? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=8efe8eede03105c63cef42b032bca85e

Comment: I used your concepts and reorganized them in the queries I copied in the updates of the question. I still have 2 minor trouble, maybe you can help?

Comment: thank you again, but in your example, the data is reversed, the login data is in the activities table, the activities are in the login_logout table. Consequently, you create a query that works correctly in the reversed data entry. I have also tryed to apply your concepts on the correctly populated tables but I have still the 2 troubles I mentioned ain the UPDATE 2 of my question text. Maybe we can somehow mix the 2 solution to get it properly work?